# How can I sort a result set twice in SQL with an aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-order-by

I have a time tracking database from which I am trying to get a list of total hours worked per week grouped by the name of the worker and the week worked.

Here is my query to return all of the necessary data:

```
SELECT [Timesheet Period], [Employee Name], SUM([Hours]) AS Hours FROM timetracker
WHERE [Date Worked] BETWEEN '2020-12-06' AND '2020-12-26'
    AND [Hours] > 0
    AND [Mgr Name] <> ''
GROUP BY [Employee Name], [Timesheet Period]
```

I want the data to be sorted like so:

```
|    Timesheet Period    |    Employee Name    |    Hours    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/06/20 - 12/12/20  |    Joe Smith        |      70     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/13/20 - 12/19/20  |    Joe Smith        |      46     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/20/20 - 12/26/20  |    Joe Smith        |      42     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/06/20 - 12/12/20  |    Robin Williams   |      40     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/13/20 - 12/19/20  |    Robin Williams   |      40     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/20/20 - 12/26/20  |    Robin Williams   |      40     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/13/20 - 12/19/20  |    Jane Doe         |      43     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/20/20 - 12/26/20  |    Jane Doe         |      54     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/06/20 - 12/12/20  |    Keanu Reeves     |      45     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/13/20 - 12/19/20  |    Keanu Reeves     |      42     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/06/20 - 12/12/20  |    Derek Zoolander  |      40     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   12/13/20 - 12/19/20  |    Derek Zoolander  |      40     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

So Employees are sorted descending from the highest number of total Hours in a given time range, but also the times they worked are grouped by their name and sorted ascending by the weeks that they worked in the given time range.

I am not sure if this is possible to do, but I was thinking I could somehow SUM(Hours) for each name and sort and then use that result to then get the weeks in order. Any ideas are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT [Timesheet Period], [Employee Name], SUM([Hours]) AS Hours
FROM timetracker
WHERE [Date Worked] BETWEEN '2020-12-06' AND '2020-12-26' AND
      [Hours] > 0 AND
      [Mgr Name] <> ''
GROUP BY [Employee Name], [Timesheet Period]
ORDER BY SUM(SUM([Hours]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee Name]) DESC,
         [Employee Name],
         MIN([Date Worked]);
```

Comment: After sorting by the total hours worked in the range, then the name, I think he wanted to sort by the period and not the hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Timesheet Period], [Employee Name], SUM([Hours]) AS Hours FROM timetracker
WHERE [Date Worked] BETWEEN '2020-12-06' AND '2020-12-26'
    AND [Hours] > 0
    AND [Mgr Name] <> ''
GROUP BY [Employee Name], [Timesheet Period]
Order by SUM([Hours]), [Timesheet Period]
```